# Swift Alamofire Unexpectedly found nil - Facebook API

Tags: facebook, swift, facebook-graph-api, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm running the same exact function for Instagram and Youtube API with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON; however, with Facebook's API I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

```
    var posts : [JSON] = []

    func loadFBFeed() {
    let url = "https://graph.facebook.com/mpstnews/posts/?access_token=\(apiKey)&date_format=U&fields=comments.limit(0).summary(1),likes.limit(0).summary(1),from,picture,message,story,name,link,created_time,full_picture&limit=5"

    Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (request, response, json) -> Void in
        switch json {
        case .Success(let data):
            let jsonObj = JSON(data)
            if let postInfo = jsonObj["data"].arrayValue as [JSON]? {
                self.posts = postInfo
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .Failure(_, let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Error output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL was using characters that Alamofire does not like, had to add a line to resolve...

```
    var urlString = "https://graph.facebook.com/mpstnews/posts/?access_token=\(apiKey)&date_format=U&fields=comments.limit(0).summary(1),likes.limit(0).summary(1),from,picture,message,story,name,link,created_time,full_picture&limit=5"

    urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters(NSCharacterSet.URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet())!
```

Answer (score 0):

This generally happens when your URL is not valid. Most likely one of the values you are inserting into the URL is bad causing the `URLStringConvertible` logic to crash.

Comment: But when I visit the URL I get the correct JSON output

Comment: Where's the error occurring? Is it the error being printed out in the `.Failure` case? Could you post the exact error output.

Comment: It looks as if it's occurring in the .Success case.  I've attached an image of the error output to the question.